# Array sorting by values descending and sort index by ascending in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array `pr($site_name_with_value)` looks like this. This is the result of two `combine_array`.

```
Array(
    [Ashuganj PDB] => 720
    [Bagherhat PGCB] => 720
    [Banani_CO] => 720
    [Barapukuria PGCB] => 784
    [Barishal PGCB] => 780
    [Benapole_CO] => 752
    [Bogura RO] => 776
    [Bogura_CO(IS)] => 784 
)
```

I have tried this to expected output.

```
$site_name_with_value_order = arsort($site_name_with_value); 
foreach ($site_name_with_value_order as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
```

It returns an error message
**Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

First I want to sort them by value `descending order`. Second if the value is the same then order index by `ascending`.

I want to get output looks like this. But I don't know how to gain my expected output.

```
Array(
    [Bogura_CO(IS)] => 784
    [Barapukuria PGCB] => 784
    [Barishal PGCB] => 780
    [Bogura RO] => 776
    [Benapole_CO] => 752 
    [Ashuganj PDB] => 720
    [Bagherhat PGCB] => 720
    [Banani_CO] => 720   
)
```

Comment: Those arrays aren't valid. You can't have the same key multiple times. Keys are unique.

Comment: Also, as stated [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php), `arsort()` doesn't return the sorted array. It returns a boolean. It modifies the original array (uses it as a reference). So you're actually passing a boolean to `foreach()` which is invalid.

Comment: Array key is unique. But I use it short form.

Answer (score 2):

First of all,  you've created an array with duplicate key which is not a valid way. So when you try to sort the array by value with `arsort()`- **Sort an array in reverse order and maintain index association**, but it will return different results for different php version. See the [DEMO](https://3v4l.org/6mvdS)

```
$array = array(
   
    'Ash' => 776,
    'Bag' => 720,
    'Ban' => 720,
    'Bar' => 776,
    'Bar' => 780,
    'Ben' => 752,
    'Bog' => 720,
    'Bog' => 780,
    'Bue' => 776,  
);
arsort($array);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Good advice for me. And first of all my array already arranged in `ascending order`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to assign the

```
arsort($site_name_with_value);
```

in another variable because it will only return to 1. So just loop the

```
$site_name_with_value
```

instead.